# Download stored files by .jpg url

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Not sure the best way to ask this question, but it relates to firebase file storage

I am using a image stored on firebase but using a uri so I need the file to not be a download url but rather a url where it is still hosted on firebase.. hence something like url.jpg (something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yDEG.jpg ) rather than something that just downloads the image to your disk

Does firebase offer something like that.. I couldn't find option that will allow me to look at the image hosted on firebase.. rather than download it..

Hopefully that makes sense..

Comment: Firebase Storage exposes a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for each file that can be used to either grab the bytes or display the file (for example in an `<img src="https://downloadurl>` tag). It sounds like you're having trouble making that work, in case it'll be easier to help if you share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: eh, okay .. using react native so it wants a uri, not sure if it'll work with a download url tag

Comment: Without seeing the code where you are stuck, we won't be able to help. Please read the links I provided earlier, both are quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: the browser performs actions primarily based on two headers: `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`. If the file is an image (`Content-Type: image/*`) and has a `Content-Disposition: attachment`, the browser will download it (likely what we're doing by default). Set the `Content-Type` to `inline` instead and it will display in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a download URL via `ref.getDownloadURL()`. There are many different options to get the reference:

```js
// Create a reference with an initial file path and name
var storage = firebase.storage();
var pathReference = storage.ref('images/stars.jpg');

// Create a reference from a Google Cloud Storage URI
var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg')

// Create a reference from an HTTPS URL
var httpsReference = storage.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg');
```

Note that in the URL, characters are URL escaped, e.g. `/` becomes `%20`

And here's an example of calling `getDownloadURL()`

```js
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();

  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

See more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files